# Не работает подключение по SSH

Tags: linux, windows, сеть, ssh, ip

Поставил чистую Debian Server, пробую подключится по ssh с моей win машины через putty, коннект тайм аут. обе машины подключены к роутеру в роутере сделал проброс портов. Такая же проблема была и с Ubuntu Server. Единственно что сделал это открыл 22 порт в iptables больше ничего не трогал,сам ssh точно установлен и запущен 127.0.0.1 подключается а с другой машины нет. Разве из коробки не должно работать?

Comment: Когда-то не работало. Приходилось делать что-то а  ля "apt-get install openssh-server -y", а затем генерировать ключи. Ну, и конфиг посмотреть в /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Comment: я же доходчиво сказал ssh установлен и запущен, а в гугле я сам уже был, запущен и слушает 22 порт, сам порт открыт, по 127.0.0.1 подключение работает, а вот почему с другой машины не хочет подключатся

Comment: а зачем конфиг трогать там по дефолту все нормально стоит

Comment: конфиги смотреть надо всегда :), даже если работает

Comment: Если он случает 22 порт только для 127.0.0.1 то в этом и проблема. подключиться извне к этому ip невозможно. Закоментируйте строку ListenAddress в конфиге, тогда он будет слушать на всех ip, которые есть на машине

Comment: ListenAddress был изначально закомментирован

Comment: в подавляющем большинстве случаев эти два действия не нужны: 1. *открыл 22 порт в iptables*. 2. *в роутере сделал проброс портов*. // проверьте как-нибудь хождение пакетов в пределах вашей операционной системы (понятия не имею, как это делается в *ms/windows*: там какие-то «брандмауэры», «антивирусы» и прочие странные сущности обитают)